# Multiple References of an entities in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-6

Here is my model attached.

[image]

Now here as you can see Employee can have many number of skills then EmployeeSkill can have contain Skill and Skill Level.

I want to write a query in which i want to access all related data from all tables

Say   here is query below

```
 _context.Employees.include(e=>e.EmployeesSkills.select(s=>s.Skill));
```

this query will include only  employee=>EmployeesSkills==>Skill how can i include SkillLevel in this same query to access data from all related tables.

Comment: so how can i do this If you have any solution plz share with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Include` extension method overload which takes an `Expression<Func<T,U>>` can only understand very simple navigation paths which use only property access and the `Select` method. To include entities with more complex relationships you need to use the overload which takes a string. In your case, it would look like this:

```
 _context.Employees.Include("EmployeesSkills.Skill").Include("EmployeesSkills.SkillLevel");
```

**Edit:**

Actually, it doesn't look like what you want to do is too complicated for the strongly typed version of `Include`. This should work:

```
_context.Employees.Include(e => e.EmployeesSkills.Select(s => s.Skill))
                  .Include(e => e.EmployeesSkills.Select(s => s.SkillLevel));
```

Comment: Because he wants two types I think it should be `_context.Employees.Include("EmployeesSkills.Skill").Include("EmployeesSkills.SkillLevel");` (Or whatever the navigation property is named)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, yep, missed that. Answer updated.

Comment: @SteveRuble `Include` also understand the `SelectMany` extension method for navigating nested collections.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, you're right. I just assumed that `SkillLevel` was off of `Skill`, because otherwise why not just chain the `Include`s? Bad assumption, I guess.

Comment: @SimonBelanger, did they add that in EF 6.0? I just tried it in EF 5.0 and it gave me an error.

Comment: Following does not works   in my case it returns null _context.Employees.Include(e => e.EmployeesSkills.Select(s => s.Skill)).Include(e => e.EmployeesSkills.Select(s => s.SkillLevel));     however i will try overloaded suggestion now.thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks for your help @Steve Ruble,Appreciated it worked.Overloaded suggestion.Thanks ScottChamberlain,SimonBelanger